# Running Rendr Examples Results in HTTP 502 Error When Links Clicked

Tags: node.js, http, express, connect, rendr

I have built and run [Rendr's example apps](https://github.com/airbnb/rendr/tree/master/examples) on Ubuntu 13.10 using Node v0.8.6.  When I click on the Repos or Users links, I get an HTTP 502 - Bad Gateway error, but when I refresh page (load from server) it works (200 - OK) and the repos or users are displayed

Here is server output for the working case - (page refresh):

> 127.0.0.1 - - [Fri, 31 Jan 2014 22:47:56 GMT] "GET /repos HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.102 Chrome/32.0.1700.102
>   Safari/537.36"

And here is the failure case - (link navigation):

> 127.0.0.1 - - [Fri, 31 Jan 2014 22:48:07 GMT] "GET /api/-/users HTTP/1.1" 502 - "`http://localhost:3030/users`" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux
>   x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu
>   Chromium/32.0.1700.102 Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36"

Any ideas or pointers to what the problem might be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem is here: https://github.com/airbnb/rendr/issues/266